# (Contact Geometry) Integrability implies non-admissible path connected?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a $n$-dimesional manifold and $\omega\in\Omega^1(M)$ such that the *distribution* generated by $\omega$:
$$\Pi:M\ni x\longmapsto \Pi_x=\ker \omega_x$$
is integrable (i.e. there exists a submanifold $N$ on $M$ s.t. $T_xN=\ker \omega_x$ for all $x\in N$).

Is it always possible join two points $p,q\in M$ by an admissible path (i.e. a curve $\gamma$ s.t. $\gamma(t)\in \Pi_{\gamma(t)}$) ?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, take $M=R^2$, $\omega=dy$ where $(x,y)$ are the coordinates, an admissible path is parallel to the $x$-axis. So if $u=(u_1,u_2)$ and $v=(v_1,v_2)$ with $v_1\neq v_2$, you cannot join $u$ and $v$ by an admissible path.